# Getting odd indentation or word-wrap behavior in pages

Tags: macos, pages

I've recently started using **Pages** more for a large project I'm working on and it, of course, just started doing something odd. I'm wondering if anyone knows what might be going on.

Essentially, when my type reaches the new-line point, my next lines indent like this:

[image]

If I place my cursor before '**been**' and hit enter, my entire line backs up to where it should be. I'm having to do this for every line.

**Question**

Do I have a setting wrong? If so how do I stop this behavior and return pages to its defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT looks like a hanging indent to me. In the Layout tab of the Format inspector panel, check to make sure First and Left are both set to 0 in the Indents section. The ruler is hidden by default, but the triangle and horizontal tick mark on the left margin of the ruler being set apart from one another will also produce either a hanging indent or first line indent (the upper tick mark represents the first line, the triangle represents the left margin aside from the first line).

Comment: I knew it was self inflicted. Thank you, this was driving me nuts.